# In Silverlight 4: how to get the color out of the Fill property

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, colors, fill

in my XAML i have:

```
<Canvas Grid.Row="1" Background="#FFF2F2F2" Width="78" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Rectangle Height="67" x:Name="rectFront" Width="70" Fill="#FF000000" Stroke="#FFB9B9B9" StrokeThickness="3" StrokeLineJoin="Miter" StrokeStartLineCap="Flat" Stretch="Uniform" Canvas.Left="4"/>
</Canvas>
```

in the CS code:

```
someColor = rectFront.Fill; // <-- error here, can't convert Brush to Color
```

which totally makes sense. But how can i convert the color attribute from the Brush out of the Fill?

Thanks

Simple Code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the problem.... there are several different types of brushes. so, you are going to have to access the color property differently depending on the type of brush you get.

[SolidColorBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.solidcolorbrush%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)
[LinearGradientBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.lineargradientbrush%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)
[RadialGradientBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.radialgradientbrush%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

if you want the brush color, and it is a SolidColorBrush then you can cast it and get the color that way:

```
if ( rectFront.Fill is SolidColorBrush ) 
{
      SolidColorBrush brush = rectFront.Fill as SolidColorBrush;
      someColor = brush.Color
}
```

otherwise, you are going to have to access the GradientStops collection:

```
// Generally a GradientStopCollection contains a minimum of two gradient stops.
if ( rectFront.Fill is GradientBrush )
{
    GradientBrush brush = rectFront.Fill as GradientBrush ;
    someColor = brush.GradientStops[ 0 ].Color
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Cast it to a SolidColorBrush;

```
var brush = rectFront.Fill as SolidColorBrush;
if(brush != null)
    someColor = brush.Color
```